# Does every Scala Future eventually have to have Await.result called on it

Tags: scala, spray

I am trying to learn Scala futures. As the title suggests, it seems to me that `Await.result` must eventually be called at some point in your program to get the value of a future extracted in to a Scala field. Here is my code so far. I am querying a arbitrary uri here and mapping it to a case class called `Address` suppose that this `Address` case class has one field, `final_balance`.

```
  case class Address(final_balance:Double) 
  def getAddress(bitcoinAddress: String)(format: DataFormat): Future[Address] = {

    val uri: String = "http://example.com"
    val response: Future[HttpResponse] = (IO(Http) ? HttpRequest(GET, Uri(uri))).mapTo[HttpResponse]

    implicit val addressJsonFormat = AddressJsonProtocol.addressFormat
    val address: Future[Address] = response.flatMap { x =>
      x match {
        case HttpResponse(_, entity, _, _) =>
          Future(entity.asString.parseJson.convertTo[Address])
      }
    }
    address
  }

  def getFinalBalance(address: String): Double = {
    val futureAddress: Future[Address] = QueryAddress.getAddress(address)(Json)
    val finalBalance:Future[Double] = for { a <- futureAddress } yield a.final_balance

   //block until the result can be determined
   Await.result(finalBalance, 15.second)


  }
```

Is this incorrect?

Comment: The most common way to use the result of a future when it's needed for a side-effecting function (such as println) is to use the callback handlers such as onComplete.  See http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#callbacks.  When the result is not needed immediately for some side-effecting function, then the best thing to do is return another Future.  In your example, `getFinalBalance` would return a `Future[Double]`. If this is not clear I can expand in a full answer.

Comment: Eventually it must be called though, we cannot pass around a `Future[T]` forever, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be called. Using the combinators (`map`, `onComplete`, `foreach`, etc.) you add handlers to the original Futures which will be executed automatically on completion. The only time you need to call `Await.result` is when you need to get the result on a specific Thread which then needs to block to wait for the result. Usually, you try to build your application in a way that doesn't need anything to be run on a specific Thread so that `Await.result` is never needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not the only way to get or do something with the underlying value/result from a `Future[A]` here are some other ways to consider:

**Combinators**

The point of future combinators is to be able to combine futures together before having to pull the underlying out from the end future. Deferring as long as possible is usually a good idea.

There is a `recover` combinator which will allow you to do something to deal with an exception occurring:

```
f1 recover {
  case e: ApiException => ...do something...
}
```

There is a `fallbackTo` combinator too:

```
f1 fallbackTo f2 // (if result of `f1` is failure case, then execute `f2`)
```

Now if you wanted the first future that completed to be the result returned, you could use the `either` combinator though it has interesting characteristics so read the docs and play with it in the REPL some to understand it better:

```
f1 either f2
```

There is also `filter`, `foreach`, and the two most obvious `map`, and `flatmap`. Another combinator you might want to use is `zip` which will "zip" results of two futures up as a tuple which you can then `apply` to a data/value *constructor*.

Also `andThen` can be use like this:

```
f1 andThen f2 // this defines order of execution (f1 and then f2 in this case)
```

**Mapping (the most used combinator IME)**

Yes, this doesn't get the underlying value out, but it can *do* something with the value:

```
val fUsers: Future[Int] = future {
  api.getConcurrentUsers
}

val fShouldCelebrate: Future[Boolean] = fUsers map { userCount =>
  (userCount >= 1000000)
}

// pass fShouldCelebrate around and use a method for extracting the underlying out when
// absolutely needed.
```

**Via Callbacks**

I don't necessarily recommend this approach, but it's one of the ways you can *do* something with the result of a `Future[A]`.

One example would be:

```
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

// Not sure what a Response type is...but use your imagination :)
val response: Response = ???
val f: Future[List[String]] = future {
  db.getRecentPosts
}

f onComplete {
  case Success(posts) => for (p <- posts) response.render(p)
  case Failure(t) => response.error("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
}
```

Alternatively we can split the behavior out into the success and the failure cases separately:

```
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

// Not sure what a Response type is...but use your imagination :)
val response: Response = ???
val f: Future[List[String]] = future {
  db.getRecentPosts
}

f onSuccess {
  case posts => for (p <- posts) response.render(p)
}

f onFailure {
  case t => response.error("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
}
```

**For Comprehensions & Projections**

Sometimes you have dependent future values, let's look at this example:

```
val ticker: String = "XYZA" // hopefully not a real ticker
val f1: Future[TickerQuote] = future { exchange1.getQuote(ticker) }
val f2: Future[TickerQuote] = future { exchange2.getQuote(ticker) }

val trade = for {
  q1 <- f1
  q2 <- f2
  if (q1 < q2)
} yield exchange1.buy(ticker, 100)

// obviously this is silly but hopefully you get the point?
```

If `f1` or `f2` failed then you can use the failed projection, something like this:

```
val f1: Future[Int] = future {
  throw new RuntimeException("whoops")
}
for (t <- f1.failed) response.error(t)
```

**`Await`ing**

Here we have `Await.result` and `Await.ready` blocking calls to get the underlying value out from a Future.

I don't recommend limiting yourself to `Future[A]`s. You should look at Scalaz's `Task[A]` construct, which I find to be much more flexible, intuitive (to me) and composable.

**Further Reading**

- [SIP-14 - Futures and Promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/futures-promises.html) (Note: I didn't cover promises at all, just use Scalaz Concurrent's `Task[A]` already;) I'm not opinionated at all.)
- [The Neophytes Guide to Scala Part 9: Promises & Futures in Practice](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/16/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-9-promises-and-futures-in-practice.html)
- [Scalaz Stream](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream) which uses `scalaz.concurrent.Task`

Answer (score 4):

> Eventually it must be called though, we cannot pass around a Future[T] forever, right?

We can - that is the beauty of Future :)

Since `getFinalBalance`, doesn't really need final_balance, let's change the code to return a Future.

```
def getFinalBalance(address: String): Future[Double] = {
  val futureAddress: Future[Address] = QueryAddress.getAddress(address)(Json)
  for { a <- futureAddress } yield a.final_balance
}
```

Now we're back to having a Future. What if we want to do something useful? Let's say we just want just print the balance it stdout.  We can describe this using a function with this signature:

```
def printFinalBalance(balance: Future[Double]): Unit
```

To define this function, we could use Await.result, but we don't have to.  We can use onComplete to register a call back function to be applied when the Future completes.

```
def printFinalBalance(fb: Future[Double]): Unit = 
  fb onComplete {
    case Success(balance) => println("Balance: " + balance)
    case Failure(e) => println("An error has occured: " + e.getMessage)
  }
```